# How do I simplify $|z^4 + iz + 1|$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> In general, I would like to know which is the best approach in solving this deg $4$ complex polynomial.

This seems too complex and I am missing something fundamental?

Comment: ah much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: I have tried to delete this but to no avail. Please ignore.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

$$|z^3+(-iz)+1|\le|z^3|+|-iz|+|1|=|z|^3+|-i||z|+1=3^3+1\cdot3+1$$

**See** : [Useful Inequalities Among Complex Numbers](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml)

Comment: This is basically an application of triangle inequality twice, isn't it? Together with properties of the norm of powers of complex numbers.

Comment: $|a+b+c| \leq | a+b| + |c| \leq |a|+ |b| + |c| $ and $|z^3|=|z|^3$

Comment: Yes I see that now. Much appreciated.  Thanks.